# How can I access networked filesystems that I've mounted in Nautilus?

Tags: networking, nautilus, fuse, gvfs

I've mounted a networked filesystem in GNOME by clicking on the icon in the left of Nautilus. However, when I use the terminal, I can't figure out how to access that filesystem. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nautilus uses GVFS to mount networked filesystems. Unlike its predecessor GnomeVFS, GVFS includes a FUSE bridge so that non GVFS-aware applications can still access GVFS data.

That means that there are two ways to do this: using the FUSE bridge, or using the native GVFS tools.

*Using the FUSE bridge*

According to `man gvfsd-fuse`, the GVFS daemon will mount bridges either at `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` or `$HOME/.gvfs`. You should first check in `$HOME/.gvfs`.

```
$ ls ~/.gvfs
```

If it's there, great. All your networked, Nautilus-mounted filesystems should be shown as subdirectories.

However, on my system (Arch GNU/Linux, GNOME 3.10), that directory doesn't exist. Therefore, you need to look in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs`. On my system, this ends up being `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`, where `$UID` is your user id. As above, your mounts will be a subdirectory of this directory. You can use ordinary tools, like `ls`, `cat`, `$EDITOR`, etc. to work with the contents of these subdirectories.

*Using the native GVFS tools*

GVFS provides the `gvfs-*` family of tools to natively interact with GVFS. For example, `gvfs-cat` is just like regular `cat`, but it is GVFS-aware.

All network mounts are referenced in the special GVFS `computer:///` location. We need to get what they reference.

```
$ gvfs-tree computer:///
computer:///
|-- APPLE SD Card Reader.drive
|-- HL-DT-STDVDRW  GA32N.drive -> burn:///
|-- ST31000528AS.drive -> file:///run/media/alex/Macintosh%20HD
|-- root.link -> file:///
`-- strugee@my.owndrive.com.volume -> davs://strugee@my.owndrive.com/remote.php/webdav
```

In this listing, you can see my SD card reader, my optical drive, a different partition on my internal drive (mounted), a representation of the filesystem root, and finally, the networked filesystem that we're interested in (an OwnCloud account). Notice that this command indicates links.

Now that we have the address for the networked filesystem, we can use GVFS tools to look at it. For example, let's list the contents of my OwnCloud.

```
$ gvfs-ls davs://strugee@my.owndrive.com/remote.php/webdav
Introduction to Arch Linux.odp
```

Looks like I don't have too much there. Let's create a new file. Now, GVFS doesn't have a tool like `touch`, but it does have a tool to save files. We can just save an empty file.

```
$ gvfs-save davs://strugee@my.owndrive.com/remote.php/webdav/foobar.txt
```

`gvfs-save` will wait for you to type something. Since we don't actually want anything to be in this file, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to save.

Now we can open this file with the default handler for it.

```
$ gvfs-open davs://strugee@my.owndrive.com/remote.php/webdav/foobar.txt
```

It's worth noting that if you don't give it a file extension, the file won't open. This is because `gvfs-open` will throw an error about not knowing which application should be used to handle the file. (If you made this mistake, fix it with `gvfs-move`.)

You can list all the GVFS commandline tools with a simple `ls`.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/gvfs-*
```